# Djangobb 'pagination_tags' is not a valid tag library

Tags: django, pagination

I have installed [Djangobb](https://bitbucket.org/slav0nic/djangobb) though the docs is very sparse. Now the problem is that whenever I try to see a topic I get this error:

```
TemplateSyntaxError at /forum/1/
'pagination_tags' is not a valid tag library: Template library pagination_tags not found, tried django.templatetags.pagination_tags,django.contrib.staticfiles.templatetags.pagination_tags,django.contrib.admin.templatetags.pagination_tags,dastan.templatetags.pagination_tags,photo.templatetags.pagination_tags,django_markdown.templatetags.pagination_tags,haystack.templatetags.pagination_tags,djangobb_forum.templatetags.pagination_tags
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/forum/1/
Django Version: 1.6.1
Exception Type: TemplateSyntaxError
Exception Value:    
'pagination_tags' is not a valid tag library: Template library pagination_tags not found, tried django.templatetags.pagination_tags,django.contrib.staticfiles.templatetags.pagination_tags,django.contrib.admin.templatetags.pagination_tags,dastan.templatetags.pagination_tags,photo.templatetags.pagination_tags,django_markdown.templatetags.pagination_tags,haystack.templatetags.pagination_tags,djangobb_forum.templatetags.pagination_tags
Exception Location: /home/me/.djenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py in load, line 1084
Python Executable:  /home/me/.djenv/bin/python
Python Version: 2.7.3
Python Path:    
['/home/me/sai',
 '/home/me/.djenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/distribute-0.6.24-py2.7.egg',
 '/home/me/.djenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.1-py2.7.egg',
 '/home/me/.djenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/djangobb_forum-0.0.1a0-py2.7.egg',
 '/home/me/.djenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pytz-2014.1-py2.7.egg',
 '/home/me/.djenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/postmarkup-1.2.0-py2.7.egg',
 '/home/me/.djenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django_haystack-2.1.0-py2.7.egg',
 '/home/me/.djenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/linaro_django_pagination-2.0.2-py2.7.egg',
 '/home/me/.djenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dinette-1.4e-py2.7.egg',
 '/home/me/.djenv/lib/python2.7',
 '/home/me/.djenv/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2',
 '/home/me/.djenv/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/home/me/.djenv/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/home/me/.djenv/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/home/me/.djenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages',
 '/home/me/.djenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PIL']
Server time:    Mon, 17 Mar 2014 18:18:59 -0500
```

Appreciate your hints to resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's been a month since you asked your question, but if you haven't found a solution, try making sure linaro_django_pagination is installed and added to your installed apps in the settings.py file.

I did that and it seems to have gotten me past the error you were looking at... I've got new errors now, but I think that one is fixed.